# Passing QString to class constructor changes QString in new class

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to pass a string (which holds the file name to an image) to a class constructor.

```
// pushbutton function call to open new window
void SelectTest::on_upperSideStart_clicked()
{
    QString imageFile = ui->upperSideEdit->text();

    uppersidewindow = new upperSideWindow(imageFile, this);
    uppersidewindow->show();
}

// new class constructor
upperSideWindow::upperSideWindow(const QString &_imageFile, QWidget *parent) :
     QMainWindow(parent),
     ui(new Ui::upperSideWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    *image = QImage(_imageFile);
    qDebug() << image->size();
}
```

From the debugger:

```
(before constructor call) imageFile =
    "C:/Users/User/Documents/SpineAnalysis/Patient Name/UpperSide.JPG"

(after constructor call) imageFile =
    "\001І뒴\001І뒯\001儇楌"
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Question:  Does your program work correctly?  Pinpoint whether this is a debugger issue, or if the string really did change.  Also, what compiler/debugger are you using?

Comment: Post the code fragment that declares imageFile.  At a guess, since you are passing in a reference to imageFile (and not a copy, or shared pointer), imageFile is going out of scope.

Comment: The program does not work correctly. There is a segfault when the image is opened. I have been looking at an example and it looks like Qt has some built in classes for dealing with file paths that I am going to look into. (I think not using escape sequence slashes may be causing an issue.

Comment: I am using Mingw. Originally, I tried passing a copy, and I wanted to see if it made a difference (it doesn't). That is a good point about about where I declared imageFile, but it doesn't seem to be the root.

Comment: @Langleson Your output shows forward slashes in the "before" , so there is no need to escape those characters.

Comment: Which line does the segfault occur on?

Comment: The line where the image is opened.

Comment: It appears that the debugger is responsible for the string being misread.

Comment: Your QImage instance goes out of scope after the constructor, leaving you with a dangling pointer. This is likely the segfault cause.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a debugger issue. Using:

```
qDebug() << "image file: " << _imageFile
```

I can see that the string is still in tact.